# Cómo compilar y ejecutar en Eclipse con java

Tags: java

He visto vídeos en youtube de cómo compilar y ejecutar, pero en eclipse, cuando le doy a "run as" me sale "(non applicable)" en vez de "java application" como he visto que sale en muchos vídeos, que puedo hacer? 
Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eso es sencillo de solucionar, y no es ningún error, simplemente no seleccionaste la clase que quieres usar

- En el menú del proyecto, selecciona la clase que quieres usar
- Presiona el menú `"Run"` (Ejecutar) y elige `"Run As"` (Ejecutar como) **`"Java Application"`** (Aplicación Java)

Comment: Cómo selecciono la clase que quiero utilizar? Perdona pero es que empecé con java hace muy poco

Comment: En el panel de la izquierda, click derecho en la clase que quieres ejecutar, y lo que dice el compañero, run as Java application.

Comment: Muchas gracias!!